# Google Analytics - E-Commerce portal - Track order flow

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on an E-commerce portal and tracking my portal using Google Analytics, could see stats like,

```
Page Views
Unique Page Views
Location etc
```

Products could be added to Shopping Cart / Basket from any of the following pages,

```
Shopping Template
Quick Order form
Upload Order file 
Normal Product Catalog page (Product listing page)
```

I would like to track from which Page(s) mentioned above, product gets added to the Shopping Cart and eventually Order gets placed, How can I achieve this?

**Analytics script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            /* Google Analytics */

            var googleAnalyticsTrackingId = 'UA-xxxxx-x';
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', googleAnalyticsTrackingId]);
            var dimensionValue = '1234';
            _gaq.push('set', 'dimension2', dimensionValue);

                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution

Comment: @DaImTo Please see the script in use, I don't have any problems with the default report data. I would like to track order flow, in terms of from which page product gets added to cart and order placed.

Comment: @DaImTo I will try with 'Virtual Page Views'. Add unique page entries/flag in a global array, push those views only when the order is placed. Will update if this works for me.